# How do you create a single custom Intellisense feature in VSCode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, mdx, intellisense

I want the following to happen in *any* file type (e.g. mdx, html, js, etc.):

- I type `IM`.
- Intellisense 'suggests' `<InlineMath math=""/>`.
- I press `enter`, selecting the suggested tag.
- The cursor places itself between the `""` marks, ready for me to type.

Because I am editing mainly in `.mdx` file types, I have to manually type each character of `<InlineMath math=""/>` and this is getting quite tedious.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

I'm thinking of something similar to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/emmet/emmet-multi-cursor.gif) but for the situation I have described above (the nesting of elements is not required).

Comment: I think a simple snippet may be the easiest way to do this.  Do you need help with that?  You showed emmet working but that won't work in all files.

Comment: @Mark thanks! Didn't know snippets were a thing.

Comment: I wish search engines didn't index things like this, adding custom intellisense symbols not snippets--wish they changed their post titles once they find out it isn't intellisense they wanted but snippets, save the rest of us a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a [custom code snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets). I also used [snippet-generator.app](https://snippet-generator.app/) to help.

```
{
    "Block Math": {
        "prefix": "BM",
        "body": ["<BlockMath math=\"$1\"/>"],
        "description": "Create a block math component."
    },
    "Inline Math": {
        "prefix": "IM",
        "body": ["<InlineMath math=\"$1\"/>"],
        "description": "Create a inline math component."
    }
}
```

Comment: the location of the cursor after the snippet is `$0`, you use `$2`

Comment: Does this matter? It works for what I want it to do. @rioV8

Comment: you don't need to TAB out of the last tab stop

Comment: @rioV8 you are right! Didn't know that worked like that. Updated.